# Dystopian YA book featuring female protagonist who reviews/endorses children's toys

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

I only read the first few chapters of this book and I really want to continue it.

It happens in a future dystopian world where most people are poor. The main character is a teenage girl who lives with her younger sister and sick grandmother. In order to get money to get medicine for her grandmother she interviews for a job where she is supposed to either review or endorse (I'm not sure) children's toys and books.

In reality, the job is a reality TV show but none of the participants know this.

Comment: When did you read it? Where? Do you remember anything about the cover, paperback or hardback, whether the author was male or female? If you hover over the story-identification tag and click on "info", you'll get a list of questions that you can answer to help us narrow this down. :)

Answer (score 5):

### *[Flash Point](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FEFAHW)*, by Nancy Kress

The protagonist cares for her grandmother, who is not well.

> The only part of this that really registered on Amy was “union pay and
>   full medical benefits.” My God, that could mean hospital care for
>   Gran, a safe apartment, enough to eat . . . Much more fiercely than
>   she intended, she turned on the woman. “Would I be able to put my
>   grandmother on my medical care? I’m her sole support.”
>
> The woman blinked. “You’re guardian for your grandmother? At sixteen?”
>
> “Not legally. But she’s ill and I take care of her.”

She wants money for medicine for her grandmother:

> Money for whatever medicine Gran might need, a new TV instead of an
>   old pawned one, new jeans—

She isn't quite her sister's guardian:

> Gran was Kaylie’s guardian and had been Amy’s until she turned
>   sixteen.

Given that her grandmother is ill, though, she does take care of her.

She is selected for a reality TV show:

> “I’m Alex Everett,” the bald man said. “Before we do the rest of the
>   introductions, let me explain for those of you who still don’t
>   understand what you’re doing here.” He winked at Amy, who kept her
>   face as blank as she could manage. “You lucky seven have been chosen
>   from hundreds of applicants for Taunton Life Network’s newest show,
>   *Who Knows People, Baby—You?* Myra Townsend and I are the producers, and
>   this is how the show works.”

I couldn't find anything about endorsing toys or books, but the rest is an exact match.